# Woocommerce Add image after product Short Description

Tags: woocommerce

I am wanting to add an image after the Product Short Description and before the Price, globally on the single product page.  How can  I do this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ginar! please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. stackoverflow mainly deals with programming questions. if you could narrow down your question to a programming one, that would be splendid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the product summary on the single product page are displayed via the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook in the `content-single-product.php` file. In this template file you can see a list of all the functions that are being called via this hook and their priority.

```
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
 */
```

So if you want to add content after the short description (single excerpt) you will have to use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook and make sure the priority is higher than the single excerpt (`20`) but lower than the following element, which is the 'add to cart' (`30`).

So something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
    echo '<img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/200">';
}, 25 );
```

If you are completely new to WordPress hooks you can check the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/